# How to overgive a template to a dompdf script?

Tags: php, dompdf

i wanted to ask, what would be the best way, to generate a dynamical pdf?

My Script generates a template from a predefined HTML code and replace the values with my current ones.

The Problem now, how do i get this information to my dompdf script?
The idea is,that someone should klick on a button and can download the generated PDF.(it's not a big deal)

In an Example I found a solution, that someone has use a $_SESSION-Variable.

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$tym = date('g:i s');
$filename = 'print'.$tym;
$dompdf->load_html($_SESSION['prints']['table']);

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($filename. ".pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
?>
```

[here](http://kyokasuigetsu25.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/how-to-use-dompdf-with-css/)

But i don't think this wouldn't be a very good solution, because my table could be between 100 and 300 rows.

The Second solution my friend has suggest,was to save the html in a MysqlTable and save also a sessionID and timestamp for this user, so that i don't have collisions and could identified him.
When the entry was 1 hour old i should delete it.

Has someone a better solution?

Edit: Now i have a 3rd Solution, I think it's better then the 2 before.

How would it be, that I save the HTML-Template in an extern file and will save in the DB the place where the file exists.
When it is 1 hour old i will delete it on the same request and recreate it.

Comment: How about making form with table content being posted to the PDF generating script?

Comment: Does your script generate the final HTML document or does it require user input? For the former you can just feed the generated HTML to dompdf. For the latter, the user could submit the document and you could generate the desired HTML on the server from the user input.

Comment: @BrianS my script generates the final HTML document. It is because the first script also parse the table to show it on the frontpage.
So i generate 2 Table with some different contents.